# Map with polymorphic generics

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, casting, polymorphism

I have a method (let's call it `doSomething`) which takes in a `Map<String,Object>` and I want to pass in a `Map<String,Foo>` (Foo extends Object, of course). When I compile, it says that `doSomething` cannot be applied to the given types. Here is my code:

```
    public class FooMapChoo {

        private Map<String, Foo> map;

        public void doSomething(Map<String,Object>) {
        }

        public static void main(String...args) {
            doSomething(map);
        }

    }
```

Compiler output:

```
    method doSomething in class FooMapChoo cannot be applied to given types;
                    doSomething(map);
                    ^
      required: Map<String,Object>
      found: Map<String,Foo>
```

It seems to me that Foo should be polymorphically cast to Object. I've also tried casting `map` to `Map<String,Object>`, which just tells me "inconvertible types". What can I do to fix the polymorphism problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

Comment: You're right. Thanks for finding that one.

Comment: Now, do you know how to close the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use wildcards

```
Map<String, ? extends Object>
```

Comment: Or `Map<String, ?>` will do. +1

Comment: Real men explicitly extend Object :)